# how to call a Dll and pass parameters to it in delphi 7

Tags: delphi

I am a delphi noob so please help me out with this. I have created a DLL with the following code:

```
 library PRdll;
   uses
 ExceptionLog, SysUtils,Classes,Dialogs;

{$R *.res}

  function DllMessage(var a:integer):Integer;stdcall;export;
  begin
      Showmessage('GHelloa');//this is displayed
      ShowMessage(IntToStr(a));//I get the error at this point
       Result:=5;
  end;

    exports DllMessage;
  begin
  end.
```

The corresponding call to the DLL is given by this code:

```
    var
      FDll: TFDll;
       function DllMessage(var a:integer):integer;stdcall;external 'PRDll.dll';
     implementation

    {$R *.dfm}

       procedure TFDll.btnCallDllClick(Sender: TObject);
      var
       i:integer;
      s1:string;
      begin
           i:=5;
          s1:=IntToStr(DllMessage(i));
         //ShowMessage(s1);
         end;
```

I get an access error. Why does this happen . ANybody ? help!!!
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Well the real code is big thats why i didnt post it. Anyway i am posting now

Comment: Sorry I misread. I can see no reason whatsoever for the error.

Comment: Can you double check the declaration of DllMessage in both DLL and EXE. Are you sure it is as you have it here. As an aside I don't think you need `export` but I believe that is benign.

Comment: I tried (essentially) the code above, and it works. You might want to try not to use `var` before `a: integer`. Maybe the old Delphi 7 doesn't like that.

Comment: There's an error in the code you're NOT showing. I just went through the trouble of actually building your DLL (as displayed) with Delphi 7 then writing a 11 lines console application to test the function call *you're showing*. It all went fine, worked as expected. For the record I compiled with ExceptionLog and no ShareMem, in other words, *exactly* your code, as posted.

Comment: And the DLL is present in the same folder as the executable ?

Comment: @Andreas `var` parameters in DLLs have worked since Delphi 1!

Comment: @David: OK, I wasn't sure, but that would have been my guess.

Comment: @Edelcom: Otherwise the error would have appeared earlier than the OP claims...

Comment: -1. Code does not exhibit the error reported. Real code was being posted "now," but that was over 45 minutes ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is posted below; i am surprised why no one could tell me this simple thing

```
//Dll
 library ProDll;

uses
   ExceptionLog,
  SysUtils,
  Classes,Dialogs;

  function showSqRoot(var a:Double):Double; stdcall; export;
  begin

     Result:=sqrt(a);
   end;

   exports showSqRoot;
  {$R *.res}

   begin
    end.


 //The program
   function showSqRoot(var a:Double):Double;stdcall external 'ProDll.dll'//Notice 'stdcall external' here

 procedure TFcallDLL.btnCallDLLClick(Sender: TObject);
  var
        numInput,numRes:Double;   {Input and Result}
   begin
       numInput:=StrToFloat(edtInput.Text);
      numRes:=showSqRoot(numInput);   {call the function in DLL with the Parameter}
      edtResult.Text:=FloatToStr(numRes); {Display the Result}
    end;
```

This code has worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added **sharemem** unit?
See the help.

Second option: Comment the ExceptionLog line and try again.
It work fine.

Regards.

Comment: Not the answer. The DLL function doesn't alloc memory the exe would need to free, nor the other way around. Sharemem shouldn't make any difference at all.

Comment: Try to comment the ExceptionLog uses and try again.

Comment: @Cosmin Prund; Ok, in this particular case it's not necessary. If no more code on DLL (and this is not a sample) is not necessary.

Comment: +1 for the second one. The first one is clearly not required in Delphi 2009 at least.